# Is there a row equivalent to the 'col_wrap' parameter in seaborn's FacetGrid?

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, ridgeline-plot

I am making a ridge plot using `seaborn` in python (following [this example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)). In my case however, I have a lot more than 10 distributions, so I'd like to have multiple columns of histograms.

This all gets set up using this `FacetGrid` command:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='date', aspect=15, height=.5)
```

Now, `FacetGrid` will wrap columns when you specify the `col` parameter, and then give `col_wrap` to be some value where any more plots will wrap around the the next row. What I would like to do instead is to specify the `row` parameter and have it wrap to a new column over say, 10 plots, but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `row_wrap` parameter. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: You can use the `col_order` to reorder the data such that it appears in the right order per row.

Comment: If you could turn this into answer, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I will be forever grateful

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No (as of seaborn 0.12.2).

But interestingly, `FacetGrid()` has the `col_wrap` keyword. When wrapped, it actually yields the same result:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='date', aspect=15, height=.5,
                  col="variable", col_wrap=2)
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, x="year", y="share")  # just an example
```